# How to make HTML elements defined in JSX accept attributes?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am returning HTML using JSX in a react component. However, these tags do not act on the attributes provided to them in the JSX? Please check the code snippet below:

```
function NavigationBar() {
    return (
     <div>
        <HeadBar position="static" alignItems='center' >
            <Toolbar className="toolbar" align='center' color='green'>
                <Typography variant="h6" color="green" align='center'> 
                    Welcome !!!
                </Typography>
            </Toolbar>
        </HeadBar>
    </div>
    )
}
```

In the above function(component) returning JSX, I am seeing all the default values. The attributes "align", "color", "alignItems" do not seem to have any impact. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If they're meant to be props a) you're not passing them into the component and b) you're not using them correctly: `align={center}` for example. But without a [mcve] we can't help much further.

Answer (score 0):

You missing a `>`.

```
function NavigationBar() {
    return (
     <div>
        <HeadBar>
            <Toolbar className="toolbar">
                <Typography variant="h6" style={{ alignItems: "center", color: "green" }}> 
                    Welcome !!!
                </Typography>
            </Toolbar>
        </HeadBar>
    </div>
    )
}
```